# how to fix content div height with jquery tocify or bootstrap toc

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-tocify-js

can anyone suggest if fixing div height is possible with jquery tocify plugin or bootstrap toc class.
in both cases I'm able to apply toc(table of content) in my code.
but when i click on left plane, entire page starts scrolling.
i want that only content with fix height scroll not header and footer.

```
<body>
    <div id=header>
        this is header
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="span3">
            <div id="nav">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="span9">
            <h1>heading1</h1>
            <p>some content</p>
            <h1>heading2</h1>
            <p>some content</p>
            <h1>heading3</h1>
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
            $('#nav').tocify();
    </script>
</body>
```

other jquery and bootstrap is included in head tag.

now when i click on shortcut entire page scroll.
i don't want heading to scroll.
similarly after fixing the height of div.
i will insert footer too.
thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Cant you just set the header and footer to position: fixed;? Don't think I understand what you want exactly.

Comment: i want the height of <div class="row"> fix. so that my toc works inside this div. so that after this div i can add commet section. then footer.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer and header should have position: fixed defined. Or you can use some of  bootstrap .fixed-top class.